# vscode cannot resolve JPA Static Metamodel

Tags: jpa, visual-studio-code, static, metamodel

[Snipet of the code that contains the jpa metamodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0PMM.png)

The Jpa metamodel ActionPlan_ is not known recognized in vscode, I don't know if there is something wrong I did or vscode doesn't support this